# Remove weapon effect

Tags: diablo-iii-console

How can I remove the visual effect of a weapon in Diablo3 Reaper of Souls? I attached a picture of my character with my one hand crossbow with a glowing/flame effect or any other effect like lightning, etc.  How do I remove the effect on that weapon?

I tried transmogrification on the original weapon that had the effect and chose a different look but the effect seem to have stayed. I am playing on a PS4.

[image: weapon effect]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What determines the glow color/particle effects of a weapon?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70003/what-determines-the-glow-color-particle-effects-of-a-weapon)

Comment: @TravisJ no, it isn't. This question is about "how to remove the effect", while other one is "what does this effect mean?"

Comment: @Novarg - I disagree. If you look at the duplicate it clearly shows that the weapon glow is part of the weapon due to its elemental damage type, and cannot be removed.

Comment: Just because an answer may fit two questions does not necessarily indicate duplication. In this case, they are asking for two very separate things - one is asking for "what does it mean" and one is asking "how do I remove it". Just because the "what does it mean" happens to have an answer that includes the information for "how do I remove it" doesn't mean these questions are inherently the same.

Comment: @AshleyNunn - Perhaps the wording of the question asking what the glow is does not cover the question exactly, but they are very similar. Closing as duplicate is a good way to help users find information. I posted an answer here, which is more or less exactly what you would find in the other post.

Comment: Closing as duplicate is only for questions that are effectively asking for the same thing, which I don't believe is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Mystic to Transmogrify the look, you'll get a different looking weapon but the same holy glow.

If you use the Mystic to Enchant the '+x-y to holy damage' on to be some other stat, the glow will change or go away, depending on the stat. If you want to use the weapon, you'll likely want the plain '+x-y damage' stat, though that may not improve the overall weapon damage as much as if you modify another stat.

Answer (score 0):

It is part of the graphic for that weapon, so there is no way to remove it. Turning down the graphics for the game all the way to Low everywhere *might* tone it down a little bit, but I still have my doubts. Doing that would also make your game look like Duck Hunt.

The only way to change this would be to change the elemental damage type of the weapon by going to the Mystic and enchanting it to some other damage type. This would result in a different graphic, but may be undesirable because you can only enchant one property and damage may not always be the best choice.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am playing on a PS4 and have tried transmogrification. Edited question.

Comment: @jeraldo - Removed suggestion for transmog because that wasn't the root cause of the glow. See edits.