# Will Iceblink be triggered by a weapon's cold damage?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I do not use any cold skill (crusader), but a weapon with cold damage, will the Chill effect of [Iceblink](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/iceblink) be applied to every attack in order to reliably trigger the damage enhancement of [Bane of the Trapped](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bane-of-the-trapped)?

Comment: This depends on your active skill. My data is from very old version, so I do not answer. Back then, most "physical" skills did whatever damage was written on the weapon - base physical, plus bonus elemental. All elemental skills, and most of Monk's physical skills, did convert all weapon damage to the element of the skill itself. So Iceblink definitely won't work with Crusader's elemental skills, but physical ones may work.

Comment: [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63646/how-does-elemental-damage-on-weapons-work-with-elemental-skills?rq=1) says skills override the element listed on the weapon. [This other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70003/what-determines-the-glow-color-particle-effects-of-a-weapon?rq=1) says that the element of the weapon determines the color it glows. I think +(element) damage is just left over from when it used to mean something as mentioned by @OrcJMR's comment. % physical damage modifiers boost physical skills no matter the weapon's element.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill At least [Elemental Expossure](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/passive/elemental-exposure) mentions it particularly. So it is not just for decoration.

Comment: @ceving Looking at the gem the description says cold *skills* apply the effect, not cold damage in general. Doing some research I came across [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/27hmfc/does_weapon_damage_type_matter/) which says weapon element does not matter in most cases. But does matter to skills and legendary abilities that work on cold *damage* such as the mentioned frostburns. Any cold damage will proc its ability, and as you mentioned elemental exposure as well. So weapon damage does have some purpose but doesn't work with iceblink since it mentions cold skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a cold skill to proc the Ice Blink effect. Weapon damage will not help.

Comment: I found something similar in the battle net forum. But is there a prove or a way to test it?

Comment: Get a low level blue weapon, reroll a stat so it does ice damage, de-equip your skills. Go to any monster that will take a considerable amount of time to kill and hack away. Wait until it activates or until you are satisfied it will never activate.

It's the only real way I think you can test it unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

No, in general it will not. The cold damage from your weapon is converted to the damage types of whatever runes you are using for your skills. The only way to proc it outside of using cold skills would be through a basic attack.